# 'who --message' -> which message?

Tags: terminal, who

I found the following in `man who`:

> `-T, -w, --mesg` add user's message status as +, - or ?
>  
>   `--message` same as -T
>   `--writable`same as -T

So looked up `info who` and found

> `-w  -T --mesg --message --writable` After each login name print a character indicating the user's message status
>   `+` allowing 'write' messages
>   `-` disallowing 'write' messages
>   `?` 'cannot find terminal device'

**Question**: What 'message', which kind of 'message' is meant?

Comment: @chirp - see my answer, I show how it works.

Comment: @drewbenn The thundering sound of a massive facepalm… erm… thundering. This was too obvious… Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-T` and `--message` switch mean that `who` will display a `+`, `-`, or `?` denoting whether the user is allowing messages to be written to their terminal.

```
`--writable'
     After each login name print a character indicating the user's
     message status:

          `+' allowing `write' messages
          `-' disallowing `write' messages
          `?' cannot find terminal device
```

#### Example

```
$ who --message
saml     - tty1         2013-11-03 16:09 (:0)
saml     + pts/0        2013-11-03 16:10 (:0.0)
saml     + pts/1        2013-11-03 16:49 (:0.0)
saml     + pts/6        2013-11-04 12:28 (:0.0)
saml     + pts/20       2013-11-05 13:16 (:0.0)
saml     + pts/43       2013-11-05 16:58 (:0.0)
```

The `-T` switch does the same thing.

#### What are messages?

Messages is a facility in Unix where people can write messages directly into someone else's terminal device.

#### Example

```
$ write 
usage: write user [tty]
```

saml on `tty1` has his message receive capability disabled (`-`).

```
$ write saml tty1
write: saml has messages disabled on tty1
```

However user saml is allowing messages on `pts/0`:

```
$ write saml pts/0
hola
```

If I switch over to the tab that corresponds to `pts/0`:

```
[saml@grinchy ~]$ 
Message from saml@grinchy on pts/43 at 17:06 ...
hola
```

#### Enabling/Disabling the status

You can use the command `mesg` to enable and disable this feature in a given terminal.

Messages is enabled.

```
$ who --message | grep "pts/0"
saml     + pts/0        2013-11-03 16:10 (:0.0)
```

Turn it off.

```
$ mesg n
```

Now it's disabled.

```
$ who --message | grep "pts/0"
saml     - pts/0        2013-11-03 16:10 (:0.0)
```

Comment: `mesg` and `write` put a bee in the bonnet here :) an awsome answer with unexpected results…

Comment: @chirp - ha! I would consider it a legit question. No bees here IMO. It's always good to push your own and therefore everyone else's understanding of the world around oneself.

Comment: this was meant as a compliment

Comment: @chirp - OK, sorry I wasn't fully groking what you meant. Yes there is one thing that you can consistently count on with Linux/Unix/Opensource is a limitless supply of things to waste your time, in a good way! I read your other comment about the face plant and this one and thought it the other way 8-)